# Embed Finder(MacOs) type functionality to my application

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nsoutlineview

I am making an application where I want to make a embed  finder type functionality to my application.

Application contains 2 windows **side window** and **main window**.
Side window contains list of all the folder list.(have implemented it using `NSOutLineView`)
Main window view changes according to the selected folder.

If a user has doubled clicked any folder (on main Window)it will open the content of the folder inside the same windows(main), if user double clicks on a file (on main window ), file gets opened with the associated application separately.

I have used [SourceView application](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SourceView/Introduction/Intro.html) to accomplish the step of implementing the the side window(`NSoutLineView`) but cannot add browsing capabilities to my application in main windows.

Comment: @sosborn :I have made use of SourceView Application.The Main window is a collection view of NSbox.So I am adding a double click observer on the NSbox(using observeValueForkeyPath{keypath isDoubleClicked) and addobserver{on awakeFromNib }).
But when I double click on the NSbox view,I am changing the isDoubleClicked property, but still the is not invoking observeValueForKeyPath.

Comment: What I mean is, what is the code you are using for the double click? We cannot possible help without seeing that.